# Linux:Handling empty argument in C

Tags: c, linux

Trying to make my own ls command, the problem I am facing is that when I pass no argument I get the following error on execution:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Following is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    DIR *mydir;
    struct dirent *myfile;
    struct stat mystat;

    mydir = opendir("./");
    int print = 0;



    if (strcmp(argv[1],"-a") == 0)
     {
       print = 2;
     }
}
```

Comment: `if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1],"-a") == 0)`

Comment: Worked! You can mention it in answer so I can approve it :)

Comment: Don't do ad hoc option parsing; use [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html)
 or GNU [`getopt_long()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) — or, if you're using C++, [Boost.Program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/program_options/).  And don't try to compare a null pointer with a string; it crashes your program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you don't pass any extra arguments to your program, `strcmp(argv[1],"-a")` will be a problem. You should check `argc` here.

Comment: Not what I asked, still a vote up for help, you can vote up the question if you think it can be useful for others :)

Comment: i.e. it crashes because argv[1] is NULL and strcmp doesn't check for NULL arguments.

Comment: It is the problem, you are reading outside the argv array bounds. The answer from bluepixy also checks for the amount of arguements which are given to your program. If argc > 1 returns false, cpp doesn't check the other half of the '&&' so the program won't crash.